# Zeroth power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am slightly confused by one thing. The zeroth power of any matrix is defined to be the identity. However, take a normal matrix $A$ and write it as $A = \sum_i \lambda_i P_i$ where $\lambda_i$ are the non-zero eigenvalues and $P_i$ are orthogonal projections on the corresponding eigenspaces. Now, for some integer $n$, the matrix $A^n$ can be expressed as $A^n = \sum_i \lambda^n P_i$ because the $P_i$ are mutually orthogonal. But doesn't this suggest that $A^0 = \sum_i P_i$, which is not equal to identity if $A$ is not full rank?

Comment: Can you elbaorate, why is $\sum_i P_i$ not the identity?

Comment: @flawr It is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $A^*$.

Comment: Is there a name for this decomposition $A= \sum_i \lambda_i P_i$?

Comment: @flawr I think it's usually referred to as the spectral decomposition (as a consequence of the spectral theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to make this convention consistent is to say that $A = \sigma_{i}\lambda_i P_i$, where we have included the zero-eigenvalues.   The matrix $A^n$ can be expressed as
$$
A^n = \sum_i \lambda_i^n P_i
$$
where we have defined $\lambda^0 = 1$ for **all** complex numbers $\lambda$, including $\lambda = 0$.  Notably, the fact that we have included the zero eigenvalue won't affect the result  computation for $n > 0$.

To be sure, though, $A^0 = I$ is just a convenient convention.

Comment: I wouldn't even call this a work-around. It takes a special effort to say that the property we want is $A^n = \sum_i \lambda_i^n P_i$ for all *nonzero* eigenvalues, rather than for *all* eigenvalues. All we have to do to make the identity work for $n=0$ as well is to avoid taking that special effort.

Comment: @MishaLavrov well, I would argue that taking $0^0 = 1$, while common, is a "special effort" in its own right.

Comment: It's one you shouldn't be surprised at having to take if you want the zeroth power of things to be the identity :)